# Object Equality in jQuery3+

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

`Sample using jquery3.1`: https://jsfiddle.net/pyb10ey9/

comparing  same objects from the two different array in jquery3+ version and it return false. I can't able to find where it is differ.

Comment: try add `.toString()` as in `var isDataEqual = data1.colors[0].toString() == data.colors[0].toString();`

Comment: I tried that but it return true for  different objects also

Answer (score 0):

The right way of comparing 2 objects using vanilla Javascript, and possibly one of the fastest, is [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Bear in mind, it was introduced with Javascript 1.7 in 2006 and may not work on somewhat older browsers, as you can see [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=JSON.stringify()). But still, over 97% global coverage is pretty safe by my standards.

As you can see in your example, it DOES have to rely on the ordering of the properties.

```
var data = {
colors: [{
    id: 1,
    color: "red"
  }, {
    color: "green",
    id: 2
  }]
};
var data1 = {
  colors: [{
    id: 1,
    color: "red"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    color: "green"
  }]
};
 var isDataEqual = JSON.stringify(data1.colors[1]) == JSON.stringify(data.colors[1]);
      alert("jquery version : " + jQuery.fn.jquery + "\n" + "isDataEqual : " + isDataEqual);
```

[Working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyb10ey9/4/)

[Very informative research](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/01/28/javascript-deep-equal.html)